# Adding EndlessAdapter implicitly adds READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Using git bisect, I tracked down which commit in my project was causing the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to be implicitly added (ie, the permission is not in my manifest, but appears in the Play Store). In the commit, I extend an adapter with the [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) library. I added the library via gradle:

`compile "com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3"`

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE), if min and target sdk are set to 3 or lower, this permission is granted implicitly. This doesn't seem to be the issue with this library, however, as [its min sdk is set to 4](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/endless/AndroidManifest.xml).

However, it is dependent on the [CWAC-AdapterWrapper](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-adapter/tree/master) class and specifically v1.0.1. CWAC-Adapter-v1.0.1's compileSdkVersion is set to 4, but no minSdkVersion is set. However, v1.0.3 has minSdkVersion set to 4 in its manifest.

Is this the root of the issue? That the minSdkVersion needs to be set to 4 for this CWAC-Adapter class or rather, that EndlessAdapter should point to CWAC-Adapter-v1.0.3? If so, how can I make this change while keeping the library in gradle?

Comment: Well, you should stop using CWAC-Endless, as it has been retired for some time. That being said, add your own dependency to `adapter:1.0.3`, and Gradle will probably go with that one. If you get a conflict, add an `exclude {}` on the `endless:1.2.3` to block the transitive dependency on `adapter:1.0.1` to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another library you would recommend?

Comment: I have not gone looking for implementations of the endless-list pattern in years, sorry.